# iOS Client server

Tags: ios, objective-c, sockets, client-server

Hello i am really new on iOS programming and i would like to build a client-Server  that can create digital magazines from scratch on the iPad as client, i need that the  server can send, share and  preview files such as: text, music, video, photos, flash files to the iPad and vice versa,

Questions are:

What language do  i need to use for writing the server?
Do i need to use sockets or web services?
why?

originally i wanted to write everything based on objective c, am i wrong? will i work too much? Thanks a lot!.

Comment: For client side to work in iOS you need to know Objective-C.

But for Server side you need to know Java, SQL(or any other dbms)to manage database if you have.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to think about the following things:

1. The app side of things
2. The server side

On the app side you are correct that Objective-c is usually the way to go. That said you also have the option of using the app to display a website just like a browser would do. If you go the objective-c route you should look at [restkit](http://restkit.org/) which will hugely simplify the work for you by transforming stuff sent by your server into objective-c objects called NSObject.

On the server side of things you have a lot more choices. You can build your own server (don't know why you would want to) or use a server in the cloud. AWS gives you a free server and is a great way to start. You there will have to write a web client that will serve content to your app most likely in JSON. Finally you have another option is using on of the services that will allow you to use their servers to serve your app (I have never used one so can't recommend any)